# Modificar Receptor Contact Form 7 (Wordpress - PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Utilizo CF7 en una instalación de Wordpress.

En uno de mis formularios, necesito modificar la dirección del receptor del correo según el contenido de uno de los campos tras el envío de los datos.

Necesito que no se muestren os correos desde la vista, por lo que no me sirve hacerlo mediante un select, tiene que ser tras el envío de los datos.

He visto funciones del plugin para acceder a los datos (wpcf7_before_send_mail), pero no encuentro sufuciente información al respecto:

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

  $form_id = 5046;

  $id = $submission->get_meta('container_post_id');

  if($id == $form_id){

     $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();

     $field = $submission->get_posted_data( 'field' );

     $list = [

        'change' => 'new@mail.com'

     ];

     $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $list['change'];

     $contact_form->set_properties($properties);

   }

 }

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

Me serviría tanto modificar el propio receptor como cualquier otro campo, pero no consigo nada.

Gracias y un saludo.